# Integrate applications developed in different VS versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am currently facing a task where I have to integrate an IMU, whose API has been developed using Visual Studios 2015 with an integration software whose API is only compatible with Visual Studios 2010.
I already tried adapting the IMU API to VS2010 but that got too complicated and tedious. It is not doable in a reasonable amount of time.

A solution which I thought of, was to implement a class in VS2015 (let's call it BridgeClass) which would read the desired data from the IMU using a simple struct. This would be implemented as a `dll` and I could link it to the integration software in VS2010.

However, the part which is unclear is, how could I keep the two libraries separated from each other, so that VS2010 never 'sees' anything of VS2015 that upsets it. Is this possible using a `dll`? I will have to link the IMU library to the BridgeClass (for example to open the port to and read data from the IMU), will this, in turn, be linked to the integration software and end up being the same as directly integrating the IMU?

I would be very helpful if someone could give me some information regarding this or point me to some helpful links. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your DLL's API doesn't use any of the standard library and no exceptions are thrown across the DLL boundary it should work in mixed visual studio versions.

You need to use `char*` instead of `std::string`. No `std::vector`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` etc.

One other thing which you need to be careful of is that anything allocated in the DLL must be deallocated inside the DLL, this is usually done with a c factory function and a c destructor function that your application can call to create and destroy objects.

Comment: The rest are not supported in VS2010, but I don't understand why I shouldn't use `std::string`? Also if you could clarify the C functions for allocation and de-allocation a bit, it would be great.

Comment: The implementation of `std::string` is different and incompatible between visual studio versions. Additionally it is difficult to ensure the allocation and deallocation both happen in the same place.